# How to format a char user input individually into an 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays

How can I take user input and put each character into a 2d array individually?

for example

user1 enters the char : 9E

i want my array to look like this

```
 -----|---|----|
user1 | 9 | E  |
 -----|---|----|
```

I want to be able to reference and use those chars individually for other parts of my program

Comment: Post the code you have tried to avoid this being a "give me the code" question and too broad.

Comment: Do you have to use 2d Array? Or can you use a struct?